# Ember.js - Mapping legacy JSON response to data model

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

My legacy server JSON response looks like this:

```
{ "foo": { … }, "bars": ["a", "b", "c", …] }
```

**How can I map this into an Ember Data Model by extending a RESTAdapter?**

My best attempt so far is the following:

```
app/models/rule-lookup.js:

import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  foo: DS.attr(),
  bars: DS.attr(),
});


app/models/foo.js:

import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

When the user makes a choice in a select, in the controller I fetch the model with:

```
this.store.findRecord('rule-lookup', id);
```

In the adapter (inside `application.js`) I have put the following statements:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  urlForFindRecord(id, modelName, snapshot) {
    switch (modelName) {
      case 'rule-lookup': {
        return `api/keys/${id}/rules/0/200`;
      }
    }
  },
});
```

The import using `findRecord` fails silently, with just a warning:

```
WARNING: Encountered "bars" in payload, but no model was found for model name "bar" (resolved model name using panel@serializer:rest:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("bars"))`
TypeError: Cannot read property '_internalModel' of undefined
```

I am using:

```
Ember      : 1.13.7
Ember Data : 1.13.8
```

Comment: that error suggests that the serializer has properly found the sideloaded bars, but can't find a model definition for it.  have you created one?

Comment: it's just a warning. I've updated the question. I've also tried to create a model for something consisting of a plain string, but that did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been bitten by this problem in the past.
The "correct" way to go seemed to be to override methods such as `extract` and `normalize` in your model's serializer.
That is achieved by creating a new file such as:

in `app/serializers/rule-lookup.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  // override here
});
```

But in the end I couldn't make it work.

So I've solved it at the "root" by changing the "flat" response emitted by the server from:

```
{ "id": 1, "label": "something" }
```

to:

```
{ "rule-lookup": { "id": 1, "label": "something" } }
```

Comment: It's a bit disappointing to have to do this. Luckily I am also in control of the server code. Thank you.